# Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "выделить не могу"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Остальные предпочтения из-за отсутствия практического опыта по данному направлению выделить не могу.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Остальные предпочтения, **из-за отсутствия практического опыта по данному направлению,** выделить не могу.*

1. В общем случае обособление обстоятельственных оборотов с производными предлогами является факультативным.  В данном случае обособление оборота связано с наличием **следующих факторов**:  распространенность, удобная для обособления позиция в середине предложения, причем между прямым дополнением (*предпочтения*) и  сказуемым.

Также при отсутствии обособления оборота семантика предложения **недостаточно ясна:** в частности, возможно неверное понимание сочетания "по данному направлению выделить не могу".

2. **Для сравнения:**  *Из-за отсутствия практического опыта по данному направлению остальные предпочтения выделить не могу.*

При расположении  **в начале предложения** такой оборот обычно не обособляется, что особенно характерно для **делового стиля** речи.

3. **Правило  Розенталя:** https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Чаще всего обособленные **обстоятельственные конструкции** образуются существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями. Во многих случаях обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление факультативно.

Answer (score 1):

Обстоятельственные обороты могут вводиться в предложение при помощи предлогов – простых (благодаря, вопреки, вследствие, наперекор, согласно и др.) и составных (в зависимости от, во избежание, в связи с, за отсутствием и др.). Обороты могут обособляться, но не всегда.

1. Оборот обособляется, если нужно обозначить его границы, чтобы избежать двусмысленности.

Во избежание неверного понимания фразы директором, были внесены изменения в документ. – Во избежание неверного понимания фразы, директором были внесены изменения в документ.

2. Не обособляется, если он входит в состав сказуемого или связан с ним по смыслу.

Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат с согласия отца украл у него лошадь... М. Лермонтов, Герой нашего времени. (Казбич вообразил, будто отец Азамата дал согласие на кражу.) Смысл меняется при обособлении. Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат, с согласия отца, украл у него лошадь... (Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат украл лошадь.)

3. В остальных случаях обособление оборота **факультативно**.
   Обычно обособляются обороты, которые:
   располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым:

Обеденный стол, **в зависимости от обстоятельств,** превращался то в письменный, то в кровать, когда оставался ночевать кто-нибудь из друзей, приезжавших с фронта. В. Каверин, Открытая книга.

находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения:

На первых порах чего только, наряду с похвалами моему художеству, не наслушался я! В. Катаев, Трава забвенья.

содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно:

Кстати, Бим вовсе не представлял, ввиду отсутствия опыта, что по таким задохлым полупетухам никто никогда не отсчитывает время. Г. Троепольский, Белый Бим Черное Ухо.

Возможны иные варианты пунктуационного оформления, обусловленные замыслом автора.

И всё же, выбрав удобный момент, Хижняк **в нарушение всех правил** пошел на обгон с правой стороны и поравнялся с «виллисом»... (В. Богомолов, Момент истины) – невыделение оборота, находящегося между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Большинство постановщиков псевдорусских танцев **из-за отсутствия ясных и чётких представлений о русских традициях и обычаях** рождают хореографических мутантов, вбирающих в себя всевозможные стили, школы, направления, но только не саму сущность народного танца. [Костромская «Карусель» // «Народное творчество», 2003]

В НКРЯ большинство примеров оборота с сочетанием "из-за отсутствия" не выделяется знаками препинания.
Решение об обособлении принимает автор.

Источник:грамота.ру

Comment: Извините, но я так и не поняла ваше решение по этому конкретному предложению: нужно обособлять оборот, не нужно его обособлять или здесь факультативное обособление?

Comment: Факультативное.